# PostgreSQL and PG Admin 3 Not Listening

Tags: postgresql, pgadmin3, postgis

I'm using PostgreSQL 9.4 with the PostGIS extension. Everything was working fine until I turned off my server to move it to a different location in my rack.

Now I get the error "Server doesn't listen". My .conf files have the "*" for listening range and it's set to allow connections.

I can remote into my server and connect to "PostgreSQL 9.4 (localhost:5432) just fine. However I need to get to my server, GIS, and that's where I get the listening error.

Comment: What is server OS?

Comment: Windows Server 2012 R2

Comment: Do you check postgres service in windows service part?

Comment: Maybe your server has a dhcp-obtained address that changed when you moved it physically and you're still trying to connect to the old address with the GIS application.

Answer (score 0):

First check service and restart  service

if it not works check config file and sure parameter set as blew

```
listen_addresses = '*'
port = 5432
```

In command promprt  check listen port ad blew:

```
netstat -abno | findstr :5432*
```

Also you can create new service easly in command prompt:

```
pg_ctl register -N [SERVICENAME] -U [USERNAME] -P [PASSWORD] -D
[DATADIR] -S [START-TYPE] -w
```

If your problem not solved you can check postgres log and send error log to us

https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.4/runtime-config-logging.html